# GeoServer - how to publish all layers from store with the same properties

Tags: geoserver

I have around 1500 layers in PostGIS Schema and I would like to publish them with one click on my GeoServer version 2.24.1? All with same properties (Bounding Boxes). How to do that? I definitely not want to publish them one by one.

Comment: look at the importer extension

Comment: Ian, it is ok, but you can import just layers that are listed on the page (25 items) and importing is slow as hell. I also don't know why is importing (PostGIS layers) dependable on the size of PostGIS table. In fact there is no importing during importing layers from PostGIS, just defining layers

Comment: may be you need to write a custom REST client then

Comment: yes, it seems to. But I just expect somewhere is already written, because this might be something that is used very often

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [Importer extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/importer/index.html) it handles importing large numbers of [PostGIS tables](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/importer/guireference.html#configure-the-data-source-postgis) amongst other things.